# Attach requestbody to jQuery ajax

Tags: ajax, jquery, http-post, httprequest

I am trying to attach data to my requestbody while sendign using jQuery ajax.

If I tried to do it using the extension RESTCLient is either firefox or chrome it works fine, which means that my method on the serverside is working fine.

That is why I am pretty sure that it the ajax call I am making

```
$.ajax({
        url: 'lingosnacks/delete/'+ id,
        type: 'POST',
        data: $('#email').val() + $('#password').val()
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(data) {
            console.log("FILL| Sucess| ");
            console.log("FILL| Sucess| Data| " + data);
            fill(data);
        }
    });
```

Comment: anything printed to console?

Answer (score 1):

The data line is wrong, it should be very similar to a JSON string, like this:

```
data: {email: $('#email').val(), password: $('#password').val()},
```

Comment: This is redundant as jQuery just converts it to a query string.

Answer (score 0):

You need to have the data you are sending in this format:

```
email=blah%40blah.com&password=pass123
```

You can do that with jQuery using `$('form').serialize()`

Also, you are missing a `,` after your `data` string in the Ajax call.

Answer (score 0):

Actually data param in jQuery Ajax method is for sending url params.
You can send the same by appending then into the url but to make the code more readable e and organized i would prefer to use data variable.
So your data content should look like :

```
data : "email="+$('#email').val()+"&password="+$('#password').val();
```

I am not pretty sure if sending params like a json object will work or not because i never used it.